# NullReferenceException com a Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, nullpointerexception, gui

Estou tendo esse erro ao tentar implementar um sistema de pesquisa de temas no banco de dados. A ordem cronológica dos eventos é a seguinte:

1. É mostrada uma tela para o usuário inserir as perguntas desejadas, e também é mostrado ao usuário qual é o tema selecionado atualmente, que a pergunta ficará "ligada". Há um botão, logo abaixo do nome do tema, que permite o usuário selecionar um dos temas existentes no banco.
2. Quando o botão de selecionar o tema é clicado, um objeto do tipo Panel é colocado na frente da câmera com um InputField responsável por receber o nome do tema desejado, seja um pedaço do nome ou o nome inteiro, e ao clicar em "Pesquisar", os componentes que, no início estão invisíveis ao usuário, são mostrados junto com o(s) nome(s) do(s) tema(s) retornado(s). Esses componentes, que inicialmente estão invisíveis, são 5 objetos do tipo Button, que pretendo mostrar e preencher de acordo com os resultados retornados. Não é possível clicar nesses botões, e na frente de cada um, há um Toggle, que definirá qual é o tema selecionado.

As imagens abaixo das duas interfaces:

[image: Tela de inserção das perguntas]

[image: Painel responsável por retornar os temas]

Imagem do painel de pesquisa com todos os componentes:
[image: Painel de pesquisa e seus componentes]

Entretanto, ao clicar no botão "Pesquisar", é gerado o erro NullReferenceException. Abaixo estão os trechos de códigos envolvidos no processo:

```
public class pesquisar_tema : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
      private BancoDeDados bancoDeDados = new BancoDeDados();

    public Text tema;


    void Start()
    {
      
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }


    public void pesquisarTema(){
      tabela table = new tabela();
      table.preencherTemas(tema.text);
        
    }
}
```

Na função *pesquisarTema()* acima, que é executada quando o botão *Pesquisar* é clicado, tentei fazer com que esse script se comunicasse com o responsável pela "tabela" que criei, mas também vi que na Unity não é feito o uso de instâncias com classes que derivam do MonoBehaviour, mas caso eu tire isso do script *tabela*, aparecem outros erros.

```
public void preencherTemas(string tema){
        Dictionary<int, string> temas = bancoDeDados.pesquisarTemas(tema);

        int qtd_temas = temas.Count;
        int i = 0;

        //o trecho abaixo separa o dicionário contendo os temas em 2 vetores, um com o ID e o outro com o Nome
            string[] tema_nome = new string[qtd_temas];
            int[] cod_tema = new int[qtd_temas]; 

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in temas){
                tema_nome[i] = item.Value;
                cod_tema[i] = item.Key;
                i++;
            }
        //
        
        for (i = paginaTabela*5 - 5; i < (paginaTabela*5); i++){
           
            if (i >= cod_tema.Length){
                
                break;
            }else{
                if (i == (paginaTabela*5 - 5) ){
                    alterarAlt1(1, tema_nome[i], cod_tema[i]);
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

A função acima é responsável por preencher a tabela mostrada ao usuário com o retorno dos temas, e o problema está ao chamar a função *alterarAlt1()*, que é a função abaixo:

```
private void alterarAlt1(int op, string nome_tema, int cod_tema){

        fundo_alternativa1 = this.transform.Find("alt_1").GetComponent<Image>();
        texto_alternativa1 = this.transform.Find("alt_1/Text").GetComponent<Text>();
        toogle1 = this.transform.Find("alt_1/Toggle").GetComponent<Toggle>();
        toggleText1 = this.transform.Find("alt_1/Toggle/Label").GetComponent<Text>();
        toggleImage1 = this.transform.Find("alt_1/Toggle/Background").GetComponent<Image>();

        if (op == 0){
    
            fundo_alternativa1.color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0);
            texto_alternativa1.text = "";
            toogle1.isOn = false;
            toggleImage1.color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0); 
            toggleText1.text = "";

        }else if (op == 1){
            int codigo = cod_tema;
            fundo_alternativa1.color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 1);
            texto_alternativa1.text = nome_tema;
            toogle1.isOn = false;
            toggleImage1.color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 1);
            toggleText1.text = "Selecionar";

        }
        
    }
```

O erro ocorre no trecho em que há os "GetComponent", ou seja, nas variáveis *fundo_alternativa1*, *texto_alternativa1*, *toogle1*, *toggleText1* e *toggleImage1*. Essa mesma função eu utilizo dentro do método Start() para fazer com que esses componentes inicialmente fiquem invisíveis ao usuário, mandando o valor 0 para a variável *op* dentro do if, entretanto, o erro não aparece quando inicio a aplicação, só quando o botão *Pesquisar* é clicado. Todos os componentes da tela já são instanciados logo quando a aplicação se inicia, portanto, o painel já é "construído" mesmo que inicialmente não esteja aparecendo ao usuário. Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão de como resolver esse problema, agradeço muito!

Comment: Em nenhum momento você atribui algum valor para `Text tema` da classe `pesquisar_tema`

Comment: essa variável estou atribuindo direto no Inspector da Unity, por isso que a visibilidade dela é pública

Comment: @atlas250 qual é a linha exata de código que tá gerando o exception?

Comment: no método `pesquisarTema()` se `tema` não foi instanciado, quando você faz isso `table.preencherTemas(tema.text);` ao tentar acessar a propriedade `text` você receberá uma `NullReferenceException`. Debugue seu código, método por método e linha por linha que você encontrará o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema! Caso alguém tenha um problema parecido (utilizar 2 scripts), o que eu fiz foi adicionar a linha:

```
GameObject.Find("tabela").GetComponent<tabela>().preencherTemas(tema.text);
```

dentro das aspas, é o nome do objeto que contém o outro script, e preencherTemas(tema.text) é a função que quero chamar, junto com o parâmetro necessário